# How to have a repeating event scheduled in Org Mode during a date and time?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I want to schedule some recurring events in Org Mode at a certain time.

I want to have my work show up every week day from 13:00 - 17:00. I am trying to replicate the result from the [Worg FAQ](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-faq.html#diary-sexp-in-org-files) section 17.5 / 17.6. If I am understanding the document, I should be able to put:

```
* Work
 <%%(memq (calendar-day-of-week date) '(1 2 3 4 5))> 13:00-18:00 Work
```

To make the work show up at those certain times. This did not work for me. The event shows up on the day, but does appear in the timegrid at the right time.

Similarly the example they put also did not work.

```
** Class
   <%%(org-class 2023 2 16 2024 4 20 1 10)> 7:00pm-9:00pm Class
```

This only makes the event appear on the day but not the time.

I prefer not placing the time in the heading because it clutters my agenda view and the Org mode document in my opinion and it seems its possible to not place the time in the header. How may I adjust this schedule to work but not place the time in the header? I also do not want to make 5 different headers and have a `+1w` tag personally. I suppose this question is moreso about doing this elegantly than one solution that works. All of the diary functions I've seen only seem to use date information. I really wish there was a function `(timestamp date)` which returns the time so I could use `(and (correct-weekday) (correct-timestamp)` for this problem.

I am using `Org mode 9.6.5` and `Emacs 30.0.50`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369833/emacs-org-mode-repeat-tasks-m-f-but-not-weekends

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I came across that post. It gave me the expression in the angle brackets `<>`. However, it does not add the **time** element in the way I was requesting in the last paragraph. This means I would rather not have the time in the header and having 5 separate headers for the same recurring event.

Comment: Personally I would use tanzoniteblack's solution.

Comment: What you are asking is not clear: what do you want you agenda to look like? If you make your headline to be `Work 13:00-18:00`, that's what will appear in the agenda entry. If you are trying to get this to appear in the time grid, it won't work: these `diary s-expressions` include dates only, not times.

Comment: The general consensus on the Org mode mailing list has been that the best (or perhaps least bad) way to do this is to have multiple subtrees, using `org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift` (bound to `C-c C-x c`). See [Repeated tasks](https://orgmode.org/manual/Repeated-tasks.html) and [Structure editing](https://orgmode.org/manual/Structure-Editing.html) in the manual and do `C-h f org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift` to read its doc string.

Comment: "This means I would rather not have the time in the header and having 5 separate headers for the same recurring event." - that's about right.

Comment: @NickD, this sounds like the solution I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I believe the most specific way I want this structured is, "To reproduce the behavior in section 17.6 of the WORG FAQ. Wherein the diary date specification and time for the heading is on the same line and out of the heading.". Having looked at the different methods of organizing the TODOs, this specific method seemed most appealing. If I copy tanzoniteblack's solution, there is a backlog of scheduled events in the agenda (`Sched.3018x: Work`) which is unappealing. Also, the timings need to be in the header, which is ugly in Calfw imo.

Comment: @crocefisso: if by "this" you mean the `org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift` solution and by "the solution I mentioned earlier", you mean tanzoniteblack's solution, then they are somewhat different: the first one clones the whole subtree, so there are multiple identical headlines, each with a (possibly) shifted timestamp; the second one has a single headline with multiple timestamps. They are presented somewhat differently in the agenda.

Comment: But it should be noted that having a headline with multiple `SCHEDULED` or `DEADLINE` timestamps is, strictlyy speaking, syntactically wrong (see [Org syntax](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-syntax.html#Planning)) and `M-x org-lint` complains about the multiple timestamps, although they behave more or less as expected e.g. in the agenda).

Comment: @Zain Jabbar: Re: section 17.6 of the FAQ: you are right that the FAQ says that the time will appear in the agenda, but I tried it too and I get the same result that you get. It seems that the FAQ is either wrong or outdated.

Comment: @NickD: Thank you for your comments and the verification of my error. After considering all of these options, it seems like `org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift` can have a nice [workflow](https://karl-voit.at/2017/01/15/org-clone-subtree-with-time-shift/) or I may try to use ICS files for [Calfw](https://github.com/kiwanami/emacs-calfw#for-ical-google-calendar-users) which includes the times and repetition I desire.

Comment: @NickD, indeed they are different. Thank you for the clarification.